# Rails 7.1 default session store seemingly expiring on its own

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, ruby-on-rails-7

I have an application running in production mode. After awhile, the session data seems to clear out. I am using vanilla Rails 7.1.1 without any additional authentication gems.

Any idea what could be causing this? How can I investigate further? I'd like session data to stick around as long as absolutely possible for my use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set expire time of your session cookie:

`Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, expire_after: 14.days`

https://api.rubyonrails.org/v7.1.3/classes/ActionDispatch/Session/CookieStore.html

Comment: This works. When the expire_after value is not set, it seems the cookie clears when the browser is closed. By setting it, the cookie lasts as long as specified, independent of the browser being closed.